# Integrating Solace with websphere liberty using Resource adapter in ejb 2.X

Tags: ejb, websphere-liberty, solace

I am working on the solace integration with WebSphere Liberty using ejb 2.x as the project is written based on ejb 2.X. I found lot of examples which uses the solace resource adapter with ejb 3 but couldn't find any example using ejb 2.x.

Can someone help me here to configure the solace resource adapter using ejb 2 (i.e configuration in ejb-jar.xml, ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi, server.xml files) in WAS liberty.

Comment: You're more likely to get a response if you tell us what you've tried and how it's failing.  Solace has this doc, https://docs.solace.com/Developer-Tools/Integration-Guides/Solace-JMS%20-Integration-WebSphere-Liberty.pdf,  describing integration with a really old version of Liberty but because Liberty has a zero-migration policy, it's likely the info is still relevant.

Comment: yes.. This doc describes the integration of solace with liberty using ejb 3.x but As my project was developed long ago and uses ejb 2. I could not find any example with ejb 2. this is reason of my ask if there is any doc or link I can follow to integrate solace with liberty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since EJB 3.x continues to support all the EJB 2.x APIs, it may not be difficult to upgrade your application.  In `ejb-jar.xml`, you would just need to update the top of the file from 2.x to 3.x and everything else remains the same. Where things get tricky is if you have extensive configuration in `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi` and/or `ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xmi`, as those both need to be converted to the newer XML equivalents. The advantage to upgrading is that EJB 3.x tends to need much less XML configuration and you can take advantage of injection, which is used in the Solace example.

However, if you would like to stick with EJB 2.x, then much of the existing Solace example is still applicable, you just need to convert the annotations to XML, add in the missing EJBLocalHome interface, and then perform JNDI lookups instead of injection.  So, assuming you start with this [Solace EJB 3.x](https://docs.solace.com/Developer-Tools/Integration-Guides/Solace-JMS%20-Integration-WebSphere-Liberty.pdf) example, then you need to convert `@MessageDriven` to `message-driven`, `@Stateless` to `session`, `@EJB` to `ejb-local-ref` and `@Resoruce` to `resource-ref` and `resource-env-ref`. And finally, perform JNDI lookups of those references in place of injection.

Since modifying an existing EJB 2.x application can be tricky if you are not using the original tooling, I've provided the following key pieces of configuration for what the Solace EJB 3.x example would look like for EJB 2.x:

First, everything in `server.xml` would remain the same.

Second, the `ejb-jar.xml` for the two beans in the Solace example would look something like this:

```
  <message-driven id="MessageDriven_1050954917281">
     <ejb-name>ConsumerMDB</ejb-name>
     <ejb-class>com.xxx.yyy.ConsumerMDB</ejb-class>
     <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
     <ejb-local-ref id="EJBLocalRef_1037123589807">
        <ejb-ref-name>ejb/Producer</ejb-ref-name>
        <ejb-ref-type>Stateless</ejb-ref-type>
        <local-home>com.xxx.yyy.ProducerHome</local-home>
        <local>com.xxx.yyy.Producer</local>
        <ejb-link>ProducerSB</ejb-link>
     </ejb-local-ref>
  </message-driven>
  <session id="Session_1051542150766">
     <ejb-name>ProducerSB</ejb-name>
     <local-home>com.xxx.yyy.ProducerHome</local-home>
     <local>com.xxx.yyy.Producer</local>
     <ejb-class>com.xxx.yyy.ProducerSB</ejb-class>
     <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
     <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
     <resource-ref id="ResourceRef_101">
        <res-ref-name>myCF</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>avax.jms.ConnectionFactory</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
     </resource-ref>
     <resource-env-ref id="ResourceEnvRef_102">
        <resource-env-ref-name>myReplyQueue</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>javax.jms.Queue</resource-env-ref-type>
     </resource-env-ref>
  </session>
```

The EJB 3.x example annotations have been mapped to their XML equivalents, and then the `ProducerHome` interface has been added.  The EJB 3.x example does not provide the `Producer` interface, though shows it being injected into the MDB; a no-interface view was probably intended, but a `Producer` interface is required for EJB 2.x.

Be aware that the `id` values in `ejb-jar.xml` are important for EJB 2.x, as they are used to link elements with the corresponding elements in `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi`.

Third, the `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi` file is needed to bind the references to the resources declared in server.xml, which would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejbbnd:EJBJarBinding xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:ejbbnd="ejbbnd.xmi" xmlns:commonbnd="commonbnd.xmi" xmlns:ejb="ejb.xmi" xmlns:common="common.xmi" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmi:id="ejb-jar_ID_Bnd" currentBackendId="DB2UDBNT_V72_1">
  <ejbJar href="META-INF/ejb-jar.xml#ejb-jar_ID"/>
  <ejbBindings xmi:type="ejbbnd:MessageDrivenBeanBinding" xmi:id="MessageDrivenBeanBinding_1" activationSpecJndiName="JNDI/J2C/AS">
    <enterpriseBean xmi:type="ejb:MessageDriven" href="META-INF/ejb-jar.xml#MessageDriven_1050954917281"/>
    <ejbRefBindings xmi:id="EjbRefBinding_1037123589787" jndiName="java:module/ProducerSB!com.xxx.yyy.ProducerHome">
      <bindingEjbRef href="META-INF/ejb-jar.xml#EJBLocalRef_1037123589807"/>
    </ejbRefBindings>
  </ejbBindings>
  <ejbBindings xmi:id="EnterpriseBeanBinding_1037123589767" jndiName="ejb/ProducerSBHome">
    <enterpriseBean xmi:type="ejb:Session" href="META-INF/ejb-jar.xml#Session_1051542150766"/>
    <resRefBindings xmi:id="ResourceRefBinding_1" jndiName="JNDI/J2C/CF">
      <bindingResourceRef href="META-INF/ejb-jar.xml#ResourceRef_101"/>
    </resRefBindings>
    <resourceEnvRefBindings xmi:id="ResourceEnvRefBinding_1" jndiName="JNDI/J2C/Q/replies">
      <bindingResourceEnvRef href="META-INF/ejb-jar.xml#ResourceEnvRef_102"/>
    </resourceEnvRefBindings>
  </ejbBindings>
</ejbbnd:EJBJarBinding>
```

The syntax is a bit more complicated than the newer `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml` in the EJB 3.x example, but basically it is mapping the references declared in XML to the jndi names of the resources in `server.xml`, whereas the EJB 3.x example is mapping the references declared via annotations to the jndi names of the resources in `server.xml`

Finally, the code from the EJB 3.x would be very similar for an EJB 2.x implementation, except the beans needs to implement `javax.ejb.MessageDrivenBean` and `javax.ejb.SessionBean`, etc.  Then, in the `ejbCreate()` methods, they would perform JNDI lookups (since there is no injection):

```
   sbHome = (ProducerHome)new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/Producer");
   sb = sbHome.create();

   myCF = (ConnectionFactory)new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/myCF");
   myReplyQueue = (Queue)new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/myReplyQueue");
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. Its working for me now by using ejb2. added activationSpecJndiName attribute in ibm--ejb-jar-bnd-xmi file and it worked